# How to merge all the nested array values having same keys

Tags: php

I'm having an array like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => m_res1
            [1] => m_res2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => images
            [1] => pcgc_desc
            [2] => The_US_GRANT_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_usn_2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Australis
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Greece
            [1] => download
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Studio
        )

)
```

I would like to get like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => m_res1
    [1] => m_res2
    [2] => images
    [3] => pcgc_desc
    [4] => The_US_GRANT_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_usn_2
    [5] => Australis
    [6] => Greece
    [7] => download
    [8] => Studio
)
```

i.e:, merge the nested array values and make it as an one array..

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Standard PHP Library (SPL)` In case the original array has a **higher depth than 2 levels**, the SPL in PHP has a [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator) you can use to flatten it:

```
$finalArray = array();
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a)); //$a is your multidimentional original array
foreach($iterator as $v) {
    $finalArray[] = $v;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);  //print your array
echo "</pre>";
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => m_res1
    [1] => m_res2
    [2] => images
    [3] => pcgc_desc
    [4] => The_US_GRANT_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_usn_2
    [5] => Australis
    [6] => Greece
    [7] => download
    [8] => Studio
)
```

**Note:**  Alternatively you can use `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);` to flatten your array but it will only work with **2 levels depth**.

**Explaination:**

```
$a = Array(
    Array("m_res1","m_res2"),
    Array("images","pcgc_desc","The_US_GRANT_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_usn_2"),
    Array("Australis"),
    Array("Greece","download"),
    Array("Studio"),
    Array(
        Array("3rd Level")
        )
    );

$finalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);  //print your array
echo "</pre>";
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => m_res1
    [1] => m_res2
    [2] => images
    [3] => pcgc_desc
    [4] => The_US_GRANT_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_usn_2
    [5] => Australis
    [6] => Greece
    [7] => download
    [8] => Studio
    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3rd Level
        )

)
```

Comment: '@Dhaval Bharadva'what you mean 2 levels depth!!... I can't understand

Comment: @SuganyaRajasekar If your array contains one more dimentional level then `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);`  will not merge that level.

Comment: you mean you specify the main array or sub (nested)arrays??

Comment: @SuganyaRajasekar please check my updated answer so you will get clear idea about use of `RecursiveArrayIterator` instead of `array_merge`.

Comment: `@Dhaval Bharadva`Now I get clear vision of it.. :) But My array never won't be like this.. :) :) Anyways...Thank you soo much for your Idea & answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to convert the associative array to a normal array,

```
// Here $arr is your original array
$result_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);

// display $result_array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => m_res1
    [1] => m_res2
    [2] => images
    [3] => pcgc_desc
    [4] => The_US_GRANT_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_usn_2
    [5] => Australis
    [6] => Greece
    [7] => download
    [8] => Studio
)
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)
- [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$main = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $arrsub)
{
    foreach($arrsub as $key => $value)
    {
        array_push($main,$value);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($main);
echo "</pre>";
```

for more information regarding `array_push`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php